# Android Firebase authentication, can't access user Twitter data which is visible in debug

Tags: java, android, twitter, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

I am using Firebase Twitter authentication on my android app and after sign up I want to access my Twitter user name and other data.

I call:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()
```

Then on debugging I see inside of zze and zzi, we have data inside of string which I want to access:

[image]

Some data inside of that string looks like this:

```
{
"screen_name": "tom_maks",
"favourites_count": 2181,
"description": "some description",
"created_at": "Sat Jan 11 08:57:54 +0000 2020",
"id_str": "some id",
"profile_link_color": "1DA1F2",
"is_translation_enabled": false,
"translator_type": "none",
"id": 0,
"url": "http://tomasmaks.com/",
"name": "Tomas Maksimavicius",
}
```

As I want to access **screen_name**, I try to access this string like this:

```
Log.d(TAG, "testing getUserFromProvider: " + user.zze().get(1).zzi());
```

But it seems data is not accessible as **user.zze()** has different format of string data and **zze().get(1)** doesn't exist. It seems Firebase changed the order of data.

Does any of you know why is this an issue with firebase? Is it even possible somehow to access this string of data on my app?

Maybe there is a workaround of this using Twitter api?

Answer (score 1):

All I can think of is using reflections, although I wouldn't recommend it as on every new version of the `Firebase` project the `Proguard` will change the names of the methods/variables.

The params will be available only on a successful sign-in result.

```
new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(AuthResult result) {
        result.getAdditionalUserInfo().getProfile(); // this will return a map containing specific identity provider user info
    }
}
```

Note: I haven't tested it as I don't have the whole environment but my answer is based on [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo#public-abstract-mapstring,-object-getprofile) documentation.